# Facebook Comments: capthca doesn't fit

Tags: facebook, iframe, captcha, facebook-comments

I have added Facebook comments to my site as it is described in official guide:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#configurator

But when I try to post something captcha appears, and since the iframe is too short, it does not fit at height, so I see only the lowest part and don't see the top part, so I can't solve the captcha and post the comment.

If I try to increase height if the iframe with Chrome debugger then I see full captcha overlay and can solve it and then my post is added. But regular visitors of the site, of course will not debut it with debugger.

Is there a way to solve this? iframe's height is hardcoded with style attribute, so, I guess it's not solved with just css...

[image: Facebook captcha]

Comment: This sounds like something Facebook should fix; I suggest you file a bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0):

Well, OK. This seems to be the bug of Facebook itself.

But while they're fixing it, I've produced a temporal solution (using jQuery).
The point is to resize iframe if it's not high enough to contain the captcha box.
Unfortunately Facebook's script resizes its box itself once you click at it and there's no good ability to detect this. So I decided to perform the resize each 3 seconds. This is a nasty solution, but I hope Facebook will fix thi sbug soon, and this won't be needed anymore.

Here's my JavaScript temporal solution:

```
    $(function(){       
    setInterval(function(){

    if($('.fb_ltr').height() < 770) $('.fb_ltr').css({height:770}).parent().css({height: 770}); 

    },3000);

    });
```

Please comment if you have any improvements.